# jquery if width is less than, change this attr

Tags: jquery, resize, width

```
    $(".section").each(function(i, el){
    var section = $('.section');
    var width = section.width();
    if (width < 960)
        section.attr('class', 'section-slim');
});
```

This seems to work fine, on browser refresh, how do I make it act when resized?
Ex: if someone makes their browser window smaller, it will add this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bind the event to jQuery's "resize" event

```
$(window).on("resize load", function () {
    $(".section").each(function(i, el){
    var section = $('.section');
    var width = section.width();
    if (width <= 960) {
        section.attr('class', 'section-slim');
    }
})
```

Comment: awesome thanks!

Any idea how I might amend this to remove the class if width resized to be equal to or wider than 960?

I added with no success:
    if (width > 960)
        section.attr('class', 'section');

Comment: Also, can this be made to work not only if resized? Ex: if someone's window was actually less than 960 on page load?

Comment: .on can bind multiple events. try $(window).on("resize load", function() {})

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in one common function than call it from window.resize()

```
$(window).resize(function() { //you can call your function here
    // do something here
});
```