# Adding a couple of custom attributes to elements when device width is specific size

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, update-attributes

Consider the following html for a link in a navigation menu:

```
 <a id="mainLink" href="#");">A Main Link</a>
```

What I would like to do is when the device width is 320px or less, I want to add a couple of attributes to elements with the id of mainLink, so the resulting code looks like this:

```
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="mainLink" href="#">A Main Link</a>
```

My thinking was to follow some examples I have seen today and create a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addToggle () {
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#mainLink").attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
    $("#mainLink").attr('data-target', '.navbar-collapse');
});
}
</script>
```

But, I am a little confused on what that function should check for? I think the link below suggests a good approach but more help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[jquery if width is less than, change this attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377831/jquery-if-width-is-less-than-change-this-attr)

Comment: The link you provide pretty much sums up how you can do this with JS. But to be honest i wouldn't to screen size testing with JS. Use media queries

Comment: Thanks NULL. I am aware of using media queries to apply different style properties to elements and have done that before. I'm not aware of adding or removing attributes dynamically using media queries. If there is a method for doing that, please share. Cheers!

Comment: Css cannot change your DOM structure only style it. But you can hide/show different DOM nodes dependent on your screen width. You can eg. have `#mainLink` and `#mainLinkMobile` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
  if($(window).width() <= 320) {
    $("#mainLink").attr({
      'data-toggle': 'collapse',
      'data-target': '.navbar-collapse'
    });
  } else {
    $("#mainLink").removeAttr('data-toggle data-target');
  }
}
```

> I want to add a couple of attributes to element**s** with the id of
>   mainLink

You should never have more than one element with the same id.  If you intend to have multiple elements with the same id you should change the id to a class.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I realized that I wanted this to execute after the page was loaded rather then when it was resized because you can't resize the browser on a phone, so I used $( document ).ready instead.

Comment: I also changed #mainLink to .mainLink. Thanks again Tims!